# How can I use an existing MS SQL database into new Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently learning  to code in Ruby on Rails but I already worked with this framework in an earlier job as QA. At this point I already know some stuff of ActiveRecord, perform migrations with rake db:migrate, etc. I also managed how to install an adapter for Microsoft SQL Server and ran some rake tasks like `rake test` or `rake db:migrate` (db: create doesn't work with current adapter, but that's another story) I already know that MS SQL Server doesn't play nice with RoR, but we already have in production that RDBMS that we use.

Should I ignore migration files and don't execute never a rake db:migrate or whatsoever  in production? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run a kind of legacy database with rails at work. Some of the stuff was added through SQL, other things were added via migrations etc. Basically, the answer to your question is *yes*, and you can even run migrations etc for subsequent database maintenance. But to get started, you just need to tell rails where to look for the table when given a model.

From [Active Record Basics: 4 Overriding the Naming Conventions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions):

> What if you need to follow a different naming convention or need to use your Rails application with a legacy database? No problem, you can easily override the default conventions.
>
> You can use the `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name=` method to specify the table name that should be used:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "my_products"
end
```

...

> It's also possible to override the column that should be used as the table's primary key using the `ActiveRecord::Base.primary_key= method`:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "product_id"
end
```

Comment: I just get migration warnings when I generate a scaffold. The only way to override them was by deleting or renaming them. Is that correct to ignore the migration files in that way?